# How should you do pointer arithmetic in Rust?

Tags: rust

I know the answer is "you shouldn't"... but for the sake of argument, how *should* you do it?

For example, if you wanted to write an alternative to `Vec<T>` that worked differently.

I see that you can make 'something that compiles and runs' by transmuting `* mut T` values into `u64` and adding to them, then transmuting them back into `* mut T` and reading the value at the pointer (see example below). It seems to work, but it leaves a few of open questions:

1. Will a `* mut T` pointer always fit into `u64`?
2. Does `write()`ing to an unsafe pointer trigger pointer aliasing issues when the data is an arbitrary (i.e. not a managed type) data block from `libc:calloc`?
3. This only works because I'm using a primitive type (`f64`). If this was a real data object, I would have to `forget()` the object first; but can you simply `write()` a `* mut T` into a target and then happily `read()` it out again later if the type is complex and has child records?
4. Is this really the right way of doing this? It seems extremely awkward. I was expecting to find some unsafe `ptrtoint()` / `inttoptr()` pair, but I can't find anything like that.

### Example

```
extern crate libc;

use std::mem::size_of;
use std::ptr::write;
use std::ptr::read;
use std::mem::transmute;

use libc::calloc;
use libc::free;
use libc::c_void;

struct Array {
    length: usize,
    data: *mut f64,
}

impl Array {
    fn new(length: usize) -> Array {
        unsafe {
            Array {
                length: length,
                data: calloc(size_of::<f64>(), length) as *mut f64,
            }
        }
    }

    fn set(&mut self, offset: usize, value: f64) {
        if offset < self.length {
            unsafe {
                let root: *mut f64 = transmute(transmute::<*mut f64, u64>(self.data) +
                                               (size_of::<f64>() * offset) as u64);
                println!("Write: [{:?}] -> {}", root, value);
                write(root, value);
            }
        } else {
            println!("Write: Nope: [{}] is out of bounds", offset);
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, offset: usize) -> f64 {
        if offset < self.length {
            unsafe {
                let root: *const f64 = transmute(transmute::<*mut f64, u64>(self.data) +
                                                 (size_of::<f64>() * offset) as u64);
                let rtn = read::<f64>(root);
                println!("Read: [{:?}] -> {}", root, rtn);
                return rtn;
            }
        }
        println!("Read: Nope: [{}] is out of bounds", offset);
        0.0
    }
}

impl Drop for Array {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            free(self.data as *mut c_void);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tmp = Array::new(4);
    tmp.set(0, 100.5);
    tmp.set(1, 101.5);
    tmp.set(2, 102.5);
    tmp.set(3, 103.5);
    tmp.set(4, 104.5);
    tmp.get(0);
    tmp.get(1);
    tmp.get(2);
    tmp.get(3);
    tmp.get(4);
}
```

### Output

```
Write: [0x7f04bdc1e080] -> 100.5
Write: [0x7f04bdc1e088] -> 101.5
Write: [0x7f04bdc1e090] -> 102.5
Write: [0x7f04bdc1e098] -> 103.5
Write: Nope: [4] is out of bounds
Read: [0x7f04bdc1e080] -> 100.5
Read: [0x7f04bdc1e088] -> 101.5
Read: [0x7f04bdc1e090] -> 102.5
Read: [0x7f04bdc1e098] -> 103.5
Read: Nope: [4] is out of bounds
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Pointers have an [`offset` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset) for pointer arithmetic.

```
fn main() {
    let items = [1usize, 2, 3, 4];

    let ptr = &items[1] as *const usize;

    println!("{}", unsafe { *ptr });
    println!("{}", unsafe { *ptr.offset(-1) });
    println!("{}", unsafe { *ptr.offset(1) });
}
```

Output

```
2
1
3
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/first-edition/unsafe.html

Comment: You should probably use `items.as_ptr()` to get the pointer, although ofcourse your approach works too...

Comment: Also consider `ptr.add(...)` instead of `ptr.offset(...)` if you are adding a usize (so you can avoid potentially incorrectly casting the usize to an isize).

Comment: From the Rust documentation: "Calculates the offset from a pointer (convenience for .offset(count as isize))." The cast happens regardless, @sffc